# write produces strange resuts in files

Tags: c, file-io

I'm having strange results doing a simple open and write. I'll quote the program and then i'll explain my results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    int fd = open("hello.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0700);
char buf[] = "Hello world\n";
int i=0;
for(i = 0; i < 10;i++){
    write(1,buf,sizeof(buf));
    write(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
}
close(fd);
return 0;
}
```

Using this code, the output in the terminal will be Hello world ten times as expected... But on the file hello.txt I get this:

```
效汬⁯潷汲੤䠀汥潬眠牯摬
效汬⁯潷汲੤䠀汥潬眠牯摬
效汬⁯潷汲੤䠀汥潬眠牯摬
效汬⁯潷汲੤䠀汥潬眠牯摬
效汬⁯潷汲੤䠀汥潬眠牯摬
```

1)Why does this happens? What did I do wrong? And why chinese?
Thanks in advance

Edit: Compiling using gcc 4.8.1 with -Wall flag: no warnings

Comment: I don't get this error when I compile and run it.

Comment: Works fine for me. You may want to check your terminal settings.

Comment: Did you check that the fd != -1 after the call to `open` ?

Comment: Are you viewing the file in Notepad onn XP ... if so, might be an example of [Bush hid the facts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts)

Comment: @squiguy can you tell me what machine (OS) are you running and compile this? 
TripeHound i'm running it on gedit from ubuntu. But thank you for the information! 
And open did not returned -1! Thanks for the help

Comment: @Blue: FYI, I ran it on Mac OS X and trying to `cat` the file produced the warning for "binary". It then showed the text with `^A` where your Null character was. Inspecting the file with a binary revealed where it occurred in the string. The Chinese output must be an oddity of your terminal (-configuration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing **13** characters (`sizeof(buf)`, which includes the terminating `0`.

Because you are sending a literal `0` to your terminal, it probably assumes your text is 'binary' (at least, that is what OS X's Terminal warns me for), and hence it attempts to convert the text to a *likely* encoding: Unicode 16 bit. This is 'likely', because in Latin text, lots of characters have a 0 in their 16-bit code.

If you check the Unicode values of these Chinese characters, you will find

```
效 = U+6548
汬 = U+6C6C
潷 = U+6F77
汲 = U+6C72
```

which seem to contain the hex codes for the 8-bit characters you wanted. I suspect the space `U+0020` is missing in this list because your terminal refuses to show "invalid" Unicode characters.

---

Forgot to add the obvious solution: write out one character less. Or, more obvious, write out `strlen(buf)` characters.